# Viewpager вопрос

Tags: android, android-viewpager

По [этой ссылке](https://habrahabr.ru/post/131889/) был показан пример `ViewPager`. Мне непонятно, каким образом без создания в основном xml `ViewPager` он работает? У меня предположения что это из-за

```
setContentView(viewPager);
```

Код `Adapter` Java:

```
public class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    List<View> pages = null;

    public SamplePagerAdapter(List<View> pages){
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position){
        View v = pages.get(position);
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(v, 0);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view){
        ((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return pages.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void finishUpdate(View arg0){
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable arg0, ClassLoader arg1){
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState(){
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void startUpdate(View arg0){
    }
}
```

Код `MainActivity`

```
public class ViewPagerSampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        List<View> pages = new ArrayList<View>();

        View page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText("Страница 1");
        pages.add(page);

        page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
        textView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText("Страница 2");
        pages.add(page);

        page = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page, null);
        textView = (TextView) page.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText("Страница 3");
        pages.add(page);

        SamplePagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new SamplePagerAdapter(pages);
        ViewPager viewPager = new ViewPager(this);
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);     

        setContentView(viewPager);
    }
}
```

На случай если кому-то лень заходить по ссылке. Кому не сложно объяснить поподробнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в Android xml-разметка - декларативный язык разметки (грубо говоря шаблон для построения дерева view-объектов), который перед использованием должен обязательно пройти процедуру инфлейта (inflate), то есть преобразование из шаблона в реальные объекты, с которыми может работать система и прикладной программист.

Все задекларированные в xml теги будут преобразованы в объекты для отображения на экране, их атрибуты - в методы, а значения атрибутов - в параметры методов.

Инфлейт можно вызвать напрямую, через класс `LayoutInflater` или метод `setContentView()` производит эту процедуру внутри себя.

Так же метод `setContentView()` может принимать в качестве параметра не только разметку для преобразования в объекты, но и уже готовое дерево объектов для отображения на экране, тогда процедура инфлейта будет пропущена.

В вашем примере происходит следующее: дерево объектов подготавливается программно, через инфлейт разметок и собирается в дерево объектов, затем метод `setContentView()` отображает его на экране, то есть часть работы этого метода была проделана ранее, но так или иначе результат один - получено дерево объектов для экрана.

Зачем так нужно было делать, вопрос филосовский - этот же результат можно было получить и передав в метод разметку.
Вообще в Android принято разделять View-слой и контроллер (активити), чтобы не загромождать последний кодом генерации view-элементов, так как это не его "профиль"

Answer (score 0):

По-моему много чего(если не все) в андроиде можно создать программно,а xml просто упрощает этот момент. В моем понимании - XML служит как ресурс для внешнего вида,макет и можно делать элементы UI и без него.
Можно и макетом делать VP,но потом все равно это плавно переходит в программную часть методом findViewById(),для передачи ему как минимум адаптера,а уже потом скармливается в setContentView().Тоесть xml - чтоб определить внешний вид,java- чтоб предать внешнему виду свойств - невидимости,кручения(крутости),цвета,фона  т.д.
Но то,что можно сделать посредством xml,можно сделать и  на java. Но на java можно выполнить/присвоить элементам такие свойства,которые в xml нельзя

ViewPager создан с xml

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
                    <TextView
                    android:text="PAGE ONE IN"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="24dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

ViewPager программно

```
 ViewPager viewpager = new ViewPager(this);
 viewpager.setId(R.id.pager);

    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);
    textView.setText("PAGE ONE IN");
    textView.setTextSize(24);

    layout.addView(textView);
    viewpager.addView(layout);
    setContentView(viewpager);
```