# что такое представления в java android?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout-inflater

Смотрел видео о разработке под Android  и услышал такую фразу "LayoutInflater - класс, который позволяет из xml файлов создавать новые представления", попытался погуглить, что такое представления в java, но так ничего и не нашёл.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что имелось в виду.

Comment: Скорее всего имеется в виду экземпляр класса `View` - видимо его и назвали "пердставлением"

Comment: в java нет термина представление. это немного корявый перевод класса View (вид, представление)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно, в xml хранится разметка, например в ней есть TextView. [TextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView) является наследником View, поэтому его можно назвать представлением. View это и есть представление.

Comment: я немного запутался, представление - это дочерний класс, или объект этого класса?

Comment: @Sem в случае вашего вопроса это то, что описано декларативным языком xml-разметки, преобразованное в java-объект класса View. Возможно [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/774892/177345) немного прояснит суть инфлейта. Если вам все равно трудно понять, что такое представление, просто заменяйте везде его на View.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо!